# innerHTML from responseText: how to replace special characters?

Tags: javascript, php, escaping, character

I'm calling an AJAX api that returns a pre-formatted HTML string like this:

```
"<table class=\"table\"><thead><tr><th rowspan=\"2\">Hor\u00e1rio <\/th><th colspan=\"2\">
...
</table>"
```

So in my javascript code I just want to print this table:

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

But instead, is shown this way:

[image: wrong html table]

Note that the double quote is there, the special characters are not correctly and the tags like **th** cant be closed because of these backslash characters.

How to get rid of this and show the table correctly? Is there some javascript method that do this, or some PHP method? (I'm the developer of this API too)

obs: I'm not using jquery;

Comment: The best solution is to response with unescaped HTML.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: No, I can't, because I can't see you server-side code which produces that response.

Comment: The response text should look like: `"<table class="table"><thead><tr><th rowspan="2">Hor&#00e1;rio </th><th colspan="2">
...
</table>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the server is encoding the string as JSON, which is adding all the escapes., so try to use `JSON.parse()`.

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

Comment: @SanthoshV That's how Unicode characters are encoded in JSON.

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.parse('\u00e1'))`, it won't parse if any unicode char presented in the string.

Comment: @SanthoshV You're missing the surrounding quotes, and you need to escape the backslash to get past the JavaScript string parser. `JSON.parse('"\\u00e1"')` works